# Creating tags and passing props up components to filter in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am putting together an app using React that displays fetched data in a card component and filters by name through in input form. The displayed data also has an input field to create tags in each card.

What I would like to do is then be able to create an additional filter to filter the cards by the tags in addition to the name.

I am able to create the student cards, filter by name, and add the tags to each student card. What I would like to do is add the tags to the student hook in App.js. I have tried passing back the tags via Tag props from the StudentCard.js but I could not figure out a way to pass the student.id with the tags to update and filter the student hook in App.js correctly. I'm relatively new to React so I'm thinking I may be missing something obvious but it's also possible what I'm trying to do cannot be accomplished in this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For the sake of simplicity I have cut the components down and removed the fetch API to make it easier to review.

The components are below:

Example of App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import StudentCard from "./StudentCard";

function App() {

  const [student, setStudent] = useState([])
  const [studentFilter, setStudentFilter] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadStudent = async () => {
        const student = await fetch(`https://someAPI.com`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data)
        setStudent(student)
    }
    loadStudent()
}, [])

// Example of student = "students": [
//   {
//       "city": "SF",
//       "email": "tom@t.com",
//       "firstName": "Tom",
//       "id": "1",
//       "lastName": "Holmes",
//   },

let studentsArray = student.students

let students = studentsArray && studentsArray.filter(f =>
  (f.firstName + ' ' + f.lastName).toLowerCase().includes(studentFilter) || studentFilter === '')
    .map((students, id) => 
      <StudentCard key={id} students={students}/>
  )

  return (
     <div className="App">
        <p>
            <input id="filter"
            name="filter"
            type="text"
            value={studentFilter}
            placeholder="Search by name"
            onChange={event => setStudentFilter(event.target.value)}
            />
        </p>
        //I'm having an issue figuring out how to make this filter work
        <p>
          <input id="tag-input"
          type="text" 
          name="tag-filter" 
          value=""
          placeholder="Search by tag"
          />
        </p>        
      {students}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Example of Student Card:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TagsInput from './TagsInput'


const StudentCard = ({students}) => {


const selectedTags = tags => tags;

    return (
         <div className="student-info-container">
            <div className="student-info">
                <div className="student-name">
                    {students.firstName} {students.lastName}
                </div>
                <div className="indent-info">
                    <div>
                        Email: {students.email}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <TagsInput selectedTags={selectedTags} studentId={students.id}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default StudentCard;
```

Example of TagInput.js

````
import React, {useState} from "react";

const TagsInput = (props) => {

    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

    const addTags = event => {
        if (event.key === "Enter" && event.target.value !== "") {
            setTags([...tags, event.target.value]);
            props.selectedTags([...tags, event.target.value, props.studentId]);
            event.target.value = "";
        }
    };
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div className="tags-input">
            <div className="tag-container">
                {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                    <span className="tag" key={index}>{tag}</span>
                ))}
            </div>
            <input
                id="tag-filter"
                type="text"
                onKeyUp={event => addTags(event)}
                placeholder="Add a tag"
            />
        </div>
    );
};
export default TagsInput;
```
````

Comment: the problem is that you can't see updates on cards and list when input changes?

Comment: Thank you for the question Sina. Ultimately, I'm not sure how to filter the cards by the newly created tags on some of the cards in addition to the student name that I am already able to filter for. So the difficulty is I'm not sure how to do a second filter for the tags.

Comment: `const selectedTags = tags => tags;` you should receive it here as an array?

Comment: Thank you for the question Rajdeep! Yes, it does come through as ["Tag 1", Tag 2", ect...] into the StudentCard.js comp. But to filter it in App.js by tag I'm not sure how to pass it back up one more level to App.js with the tags and student id. Something like [{"tags": ["Tag 1", Tag 2"], "studentId": 2}] to pass to App.js so I can concat to the student hook